# BeautifulSoup 4: select all divs with at least one child p tag with specific class

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'd like to extract a list of `div`s (including their children, for further processing) which contain one or more `<p class="c8">` child tags, using BeautifulSoup 4, but I haven't had any luck using the CSS selector syntax. Can I use `find_all` and a boolean function, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to approach the problem. One, is to locate all `p` elements having `class="c8"` and [find the parent](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) `div` element:

```
for p in soup.find_all("p", class_="c8"):
    div = p.find_parent("div")
```

You can also [write a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to find all `div` elements checking that there is a desired child:

```
def filter_div(elm):
    return elm.name == "div" and elm.find("p", class_="c8")

for div in soup.find_all(filter_div):
    # do smth with div
```